# Android Studio: Default Activity Not Found and than USB Debugging not woking

Tags: android, android-studio, android-activity, usb-debugging

I re-installed my Android Studio. My first problem was, that when I try to run my Activity, I got an error:

> Default Activity Not Found

. So I change the configuration, instead of choosing Default Activity in the Launch Option I choose Nothing.

I think this is the problem why nothing is happening after I run the project. It's make sense, cuz nothing is lauch or am I wrong?

The Android Studio see my device and it's connecting via USB. I done this before, so I know that I have to allow USB Debugging on my device and i did. After I hit run, start to loading, and than it's says that:

> Install succesfully finished in 212 ms. App restart succedful without
> requiring a re-install.

But nothing is happening neither in my computer or my phone.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In order to start your App, it needs an "entry point". You can define it in the `AndroidManifest.xml` file like:

```xml
<activity android:name="com.myapp.MainActivity">
    <intent-filter>
        <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />
        <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
    </intent-filter>
</activity>
```

In the first line you add the package path + your Activity you want to open at startup. The reason why you got the error msg `Default Activity not found` probably is, that you created a project without an Activity.
To create a new Activity simply right-click to the package in Android Studio -> select `New` -> `Activity` -> and then e.g. `Empty Activity`

Answer (score 0):

Just add a **filter tag** in the **Manifest.xml file** to the activity that you want the to starts with

```
<intent-filter>
    <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />
    <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
</intent-filter>
```